# How to Check column value null or not before Map in property in Nhibernate

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a property called **MyValue**. Need to map column `value("Total")` to that property. before mapping need to check whether column value null or not. If null, map another column `value("Count")` to that.

How do I proceed this,

this is done for Total Value

```
 Map(x => x.MyValue)
       .Column("Total")
       .CustomType("Decimal")
       .Access.Property()
       .Generated.Never()
       .CustomSqlType("decimal")
       .Precision(9).Scale(2);
```

Comment: I think your question may stem from a slight misunderstanding - the mappings you setup aren't executed every time NHibernate needs to read or write something. They are executed exactly once (when you setup the session factory). Radim's answer is good.

Answer (score 4):

In case that you are talking about having two columns in DB and want to work with them on Application tier as one ... you should map them with FORMULA.

```
 Map(x => x.MyValue)
       //.Column("Total")
       .Formula("ISNULL(Total, Count)")
       ...
```

*NOTE: that should always be treated as readonly - if you need to write to both columns, map them separately, and create this third readonly mapping for the ISNULL formula...*

Check the doc: [5.1.10. property](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-property)